# Auto Replace the text in a column after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

My below code is replacing the value properly when I run the macro. However, I want this macro to run soon after I paste the value or string in a cell.... means  as I paste a value it should automatically change/replace the value without I push to run button on the macro...
For example when I paste data in sheet1  FHH, FGA it should automatically replace it "FST", "FPT".... Like auto replacing after pasting.

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("FHH", "FGA")
rplcList = Array("FST", "FPT")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht
  
  Next x

End Sub
```

[image: The below should auto-replace the value in column 2 after pasting]

Comment: What have you tried to do to do /enable that ? Try to do it and if you have problems or get stuck ask again with what you've tried to do/make happen.

Comment: what to enable?

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to run your replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put This code in the Thisworkbook, Workbook_Sheetchange event.
It has the advantages that you do not have to put in into all sheets and you do not have to loop through all the sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    fndList = Array("FHH", "FGA")
    rplcList = Array("FST", "FPT")
    'Loop through each item in Array lists
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
          Target.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next x
End Sub
```